# How to validate Word document(.docx) has been Corrupted or not -by using Open Xml

Tags: c#, openxml

Is there any way to validate Word document(.docx) has been corrupted or not -by using Open Xml?
For ex- while opening Word document it shows error

> Word found unreadable content ...

I tried with OpenXmlValidator - Validate method but it always throws errors even if the document is valid and open, So I can't rely on this validation.

Comment: [How to Validate a Word Document using OpenXML SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/how-to-validate-a-word-processing-document)

Comment: I have tried this validation approach, but it always throws validation errors even the document is good to open.